# Rotating a TikZ drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn xyz axes and a cube, in which I have drawn some extra lines, using the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm,z=0.24cm]
\draw[->] (xyz cs:x=0) -- (xyz cs:x=20) node[above] {$r_1$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:y=0) -- (xyz cs:y=20) node[right] {$r_3$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:z=0) -- (xyz cs:z=-16) node[below] {$r_2$};
\draw[dashed, gray, ultra thin] (xyz cs:x=0) -- (xyz cs:x=-8);
\draw[dashed, gray, ultra thin] (xyz cs:y=0) -- (xyz cs:y=-8);
\draw[dashed, gray, ultra thin] (xyz cs:z=0) -- (xyz cs:z=8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=0, y=0, z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=10, y=10, z=0);
\draw (xyz cs: x=0, y=0, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=0 ,y=10 ,z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=10 ,y=10 ,z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=0, y=10, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=0 ,y=10,z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=0, y=10, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=10,y=10,z=0);
\draw (xyz cs: x=0, y=10, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=10,y=10,z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=10, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=10,y=10,z=0);
% inner line:
\draw [dashed, blue, line width=0.7mm] (xyz cs: x=5, y=5, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=5, y=5, z=-8);
\node[blue,fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt] at (5,5,0) {};
\node[blue,fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt] at (5,5,-8) {};
\draw [dashed, thin] (xyz cs:x=5,y=0,z=-8) -- (xyz cs:x=5,y=10,z=-8);
\draw [dashed, thin] (xyz cs:x=0,y=5,z=-8) -- (xyz cs:x=10,y=5,z=-8);
\draw [dashed, thin] (xyz cs:x=5,y=0,z=0) -- (xyz cs:x=5,y=10,z=0);
\draw [dashed, thin] (xyz cs:x=0,y=5,z=0) -- (xyz cs:x=10,y=5,z=0);
\draw[thick] (xyz cs: x=5,y=0.3,z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=5,y=-0.3,z=0) node[below=3pt] {$\mu_1$};
\draw[thick] (xyz cs: x=-0.3,y=5,z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=0.3,y=5,z=0) node[left=6pt] {$\mu_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know this is probably very amateuristic and can be done a lot easier -- this is the first time I ever used this, so I'm still in the learning process :)

Is it possible to rotate the whole thing about the y-axis (labeled r3)? Preferably just by an extra command, not by editing the whole code. Because right now some lines (almost) coincide, distorting the 3D effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `rotate around y=<angle>` key to the `tikzpicture` options. Another possibility might be to play around with the unit vectors for x,y,z, though that is less convenient.

Note: You can specify coordinates in the `xyz` coordinate system with `(x,y,z)`, you don't have to use `xyz cs: ...`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4cm,y=0.4cm,z=0.24cm,rotate around y=10]
%     \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.3cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,0.3cm)},z={(0.2cm,0.2cm)}] % this is just an example showing how to set unit vectors, rather than lengths. It doesn't reproduce the rotate around y example
\draw[->] (xyz cs:x=0) -- (xyz cs:x=20) node[above] {$r_1$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:y=0) -- (xyz cs:y=20) node[right] {$r_3$};
\draw[->] (xyz cs:z=0) -- (xyz cs:z=-16) node[below] {$r_2$};
\draw[dashed, gray, ultra thin] (xyz cs:x=0) -- (xyz cs:x=-8);
\draw[dashed, gray, ultra thin] (xyz cs:y=0) -- (xyz cs:y=-8);
\draw[dashed, gray, ultra thin] (xyz cs:z=0) -- (xyz cs:z=8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=0, y=0, z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=10, y=10, z=0);
\draw (xyz cs: x=0, y=0, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=0 ,y=10 ,z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=0, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=10 ,y=10 ,z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=0, y=10, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=0 ,y=10,z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=0, y=10, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=10,y=10,z=0);
\draw (xyz cs: x=0, y=10, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=10,y=10,z=-8);
\draw (xyz cs: x=10, y=10, z=-8) -- (xyz cs: x=10,y=10,z=0);
% inner line:
\draw [dashed, blue, line width=0.7mm] (xyz cs: x=5, y=5, z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=5, y=5, z=-8);
\node[blue,fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt] at (5,5,0) {};
\node[blue,fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt] at (5,5,-8) {};
\draw [dashed, thin] (xyz cs:x=5,y=0,z=-8) -- (xyz cs:x=5,y=10,z=-8);
\draw [dashed, thin] (xyz cs:x=0,y=5,z=-8) -- (xyz cs:x=10,y=5,z=-8);
\draw [dashed, thin] (xyz cs:x=5,y=0,z=0) -- (xyz cs:x=5,y=10,z=0);
\draw [dashed, thin] (xyz cs:x=0,y=5,z=0) -- (xyz cs:x=10,y=5,z=0);
\draw[thick] (xyz cs: x=5,y=0.3,z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=5,y=-0.3,z=0) node[below=3pt] {$\mu_1$};
\draw[thick] (xyz cs: x=-0.3,y=5,z=0) -- (xyz cs: x=0.3,y=5,z=0) node[left=6pt] {$\mu_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Also thanks for the tip on the coordinates.